# Tkinter image overlay

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I have been going through examples on image overlay for tkinter with no success. I have a program that has a text entry widget and a bunch of button. I'm trying to figure out how I can overlay an image in the GUI window. It doesn't need to be transparent. Whats the most simple way to overlay an image in a tkinter window.

Here is how my window is set up:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.P = tk.Text(self, borderwidth=0, height=1, width=5, font= ("italic",))  # textbox sixe
        self.P.configure(fg="red", bg="black", font=("italic", 39))
        self.P.place(x=1, y=1)
        self.P.insert(tk.END, label)
        self.T = tk.Text(self, borderwidth=0, height=2, width=5, font=( 
        "italic", 65))
        self.T.place(x=2, y=58)
        self.button7 = Button(self, text="Show Options", command=self.enableOptions, fg="blue", font="bold")
        self.button7.place(x=152, y=1)
        self.updateWidgets()
```

I need an example using this code to get a photo to overlay the GUI screen, I have all the image modules and PIL installed.

Comment: I am not sure about what you want to achieve exactly, but if what you want to do is use an image as a background for the GUI, I don't think it is possible with tkinter, except if everything is in a canvas (and the text widget won't be transparent).

Comment: That's what iv'e been reading. I might just have to re-write this with canvas. What i'm trying to do is make a image popup when a flag is thrown

Comment: @j_4321: tkinter supports using images as a background, though this question isn't about a backgroiund image.

Comment: well a background image can work if i can resize, position, and make it appear when a flag is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to display image as background.

```
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(image_location_in your system)
background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Also note image must be in .gif format only.